# CDF of $U=(1−X)Y+ XZ$ iid Bernoulli RVs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y,Z$ be independent and identically distributed Bernoulli Random Variables with parameter $p$. I am looking for a way to compute the Comulative Distribution Funktion of $U=(1−X)Y+ XZ$

I have only come across easier examples where 2 simple case differentiations were enough but I can't see a simple solution for this one.
Am I missing something?

Bonus points for $\mathbb{E}[U]$ and $Var[U]$

Comment: Bonus points for showing a little effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $U=Y$ if $X=0$ and $U=Z$ if $X=1$. So $U\in\{0,1\}$.

Thus $P(U=0)=P(X=0,Y=0)+P(X=1,Z=0)=(1-p)^2+p(1-p)=1-p$ and therefore $P(U=1)=p$.

So $E(U)=p$ and $Var(U)=E(U^2)-(E(U))^2=p-p^2=p(1-p)$.

Answer (score 1):

if we condition on $X$ we can use the independence to get the following for $u \in \mathbb R$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P (U \leq u) &= \mathbb P ( U \leq u \mid X=1) \cdot \mathbb P (X=1)+\mathbb P ( U \leq u \mid X=0) \cdot \mathbb P (X=0) \\
&= \mathbb P (Z \leq u \mid X=1) \cdot p+\mathbb P (Y \leq u \mid X=0) \cdot (1-p)\\
&=\mathbb P (Z \leq u) \cdot p+\mathbb P (Y \leq u) \cdot (1-p)\\
&=\begin{cases}
0\cdot p + 0 \cdot (1-p) = 0, & \text{if} \ u<0, \\
p\cdot p + p\cdot (1-p) = p, & \text{if} \ u \in [0,1), \\
1\cdot p + 1 \cdot (1-p) = 1, &\text{if} \  u\geq 1.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
In particular $U$ has the same distribution as $X,Y$ and $Z$.
Hence
$$
\mathbb{E}[U]=\mathbb{E}[X]=p, \quad Var(U)=Var(X)=p\cdot(1-p).
$$